# Coded language puzzle!!

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, cryptography

Here is a puzzle I can't crack. It goes like this:

In a certain coded language

MANGO=3/5

ORANGE=2/6

APPLE=1/5

Then, POTATO=??

The answer is 5/6. I would like to know to arrive at the answer.

Comment: This is "[today's puzzle](http://www.m4maths.com/today_puzzle.php)", still opened for submissions!

Comment: Anyway...I was browsing the net for puzzles when I came across this one!! Is mentioning the source mandatory here!! I don't know..Sorry, if I had broken any rule or law.. but this was just for curiosity...Moreover I don't think..if off topic..would have loved to see the various techniques thought of so as to derive at the answer...

Comment: Solving the tasks for open competitions here is aiding in cheating, and we have no way to know that the solution will not be used that way (either by the OP or by someone who just happens to find the solution provided here). If it's just a curiosity, next time wait for the submissions deadline to pass. As for providing the source, I'd say that it's an honest thing to do in such situations. As for being off-topic, just because it has numbers, it doesn't mean it's mathematics.

Comment: Okk.. I understand...Then I will ask the moderators to better delete this post.. This could really be aiding someone to cheat...I personally don't want that. However I couldn't agree with the "off-topic thing". Maybe our opinions differ..but no hard feelings!!

Comment: No need to delete anymore, as the competition is over (and the solution is available there). No hard feelings for the off-topic opinion; I never claim that mine is the only right. The post was locked because 4 more people (all before my comment above!) shared my view. Also, do look at the official solution. It still doesn't think it is "mathematics".

Comment: Hhmm..Let's check out the various solutions,people have to offer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: It appears that the denominator is the number of letters in the word. The numerator also appears to be a count: specifically, it appears to be the number of letters of the word that come from a certain $3$-letter set. That is, there are three letters, $\ell_1,\ell_2$, and $\ell_3$, such that MANGO contains all $3$ of them, ORANGE contains $2$ of them, and APPLE contains just one of them. Once you identity these three letters (which can be arranged to form a common word), see how many of them are in POTATO.

Note that there may be other solutions leading to different answers.

Comment: Hmm.. This is only what the puzzle said..nothing more!! Still trying to figure out that 3 letter set!!

Comment: Instead of the $3$-letter set you are thinking about one could instead use a set of $4$ consecutive letters to get the same answers for the three given words, however the answer for POTATO will differ.

Comment: @Sam: So one could. Though one would then have to decide whether the numerator counts types or tokens.

Comment: Yup..Considering the 3 letter set is I think in this case should be good!! I figured out that 3 letter set..and saw the pattern..but let's wait what others would add...

Comment: Also instead of the $3$-letter set and the $4$ letter set of consecutive letters one could also use a $4$ letter set of non-consecutive letters (as Ross Millikan hinted to in his answer) and get a different answer still

Answer (score 5):

My reasoning would be:

The denominator is the number of letters in the word. The numerator is the longest initial segment that forms an English word.

MANGO - MAN = 3

ORANGE - OR = 2

APPLE - A = 1

Then, POTATO - POT = 3

Answer 3/6

Comment: I consider this the best answer.

Comment: I like this one, but still claim the others are reasonable answers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: obviously, I edited my answer.

Comment: Me too.. 'A' is not a word!! It's a letter!!

Comment: @user93470: It’s both. Of course nowadays one might quibble that APP has become a word ...

Comment: I like this one, but "ORA" (plural of os), "ORANG" (short for orangutan), and "APP" (short for application) are all technically English words (at least according to the google dictionary).

Comment: We can put a constraint that the word should not contain repeating letters and only one vowel. Or just mention - only nouns in their singular form, no abbreviations

Answer (score 2):

I would claim there is not enough information.  It appears we are counting the fraction of letters in the word that come from some set.  From the first two, we know that $M$ counts, $E,R$ do not, and we have two out of $A,N,G,O$.  The third tells us that  one of $A$ or $L$ counts, the other and $P$ do not.  So it could be $1,2,$ or $3$